# Trying to parse special characters to retrieve JSON element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, node-red

I need help on a university project I am working on with NodeRed. I am integrating a JSON API in JS (NodeRed) and hit a roadblock. Here's the kind of JSON I'm retrieving:

```
{"@SpeciesCode":"NO2","@MeasurementDateGMT":"2016-04-04 00:00:00","@Value":"58.2"}
```

That "@" sign is really giving me all sorts of troubles because wether I use JSON.parse or stringify or escaping, it is either telling me " Unexpected token @" or just "undefined value".

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
var body = msg.payload;
var bodyParsed = JSON.parse(body);
var data = bodyParsed.AirQualityData.Data;
var valueStr="@Value";
var value=JSON.stringify(valueStr);
var valueParsed=JSON.parse(value);
var element = data[0].valueParsed;
return {payload:element};
```

If you want to have a go at it, here's the URL to the data: http://api.erg.kcl.ac.uk/AirQuality/Data/Site/SiteCode=WM6/StartDate=2016-04-04/EndDate=2016-05-04/Json

### **[UPDATE: SOLVED] Thanks to [jcubic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387194/jcubic) who provided the solution in the comments below:**

> to access property using a variable you need to use bracket notation: 
>   var element = data[0][valueParsed]; also you don't need to stringify and parse @value just use data[0]["@Value"]

So the new code is

```
var body = msg.payload;
var bodyParsed = JSON.parse(body);
var data = bodyParsed.AirQualityData.Data;
var element = data[0]["@Value"];
return {payload:element};
```

Comment: to access property using a variable you need to use bracket notation: `var element = data[0][valueParsed];` also you don't need to stringify and parse @value just use `data[0]["@Value"]`

Comment: Thanks! That worked, this is the first time I see this notation.